# How to speed up chrome in Watir?

Tags: google-chrome, watir

I am using watir for automating my web application in Chrome browser. Although it hasn't been that bad, it has been very slow while entering values in the form compared to IE. Do we have any code or command in Watir web driver like we have for IE as shown below such that we can speed up execution?

IE speed up execution command

Browser.speed = :fast

Every little bit of help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

watir-webdriver builds on top of selenium-webdriver, and the Chrome driver has recently been rewritten with vast improvements in both speed and reliability. Make sure you have the latest version of both gems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your gracious response, Jarib. Yes, i am currently using latest version of Chrome driver but it's been really slow and time-consuming entering values in form compared to other automation tools such as SAHI. Also i am seeing consistent "Aw Snap" errors on chrome while running from watir. Is there anyway we can minimize aw snap errors and run the application in chrome more faster?     Thanks- Ash